# Fatal error lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7.2, mcrypt

When accessing payment methods menu in admin panel (Magento 1.9.2.2)  I get the following fatal error.
[image: backend error]
And in the frontend this:
[image: frontend error]
I asked my hosting company to instal mCrypt module on Server as shown on the screenshots below [image: hosting mcrypt]
[image: hosting2]
but nothing changed even after the server restart.

Is there some other solution that can help us solve the fatal error?

Comment: which php version you are using?

Comment: The current version of PHP is 7.2.17 .

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases, this issue comes in php updated version i.e. `php7` and if `mcrypt` is not installed -

to install it, follow the below steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo service apache2 restart
```